# xmonad and read it later

Tags: linux, haskell, firefox-addon, window-managers, xmonad

I am using xmonad and the read it later extension for firefox. Now, if I want to tag an entry in the read it later list, the list disappears (instead of giving simply focus to to tag textfield) and a very small empty window occurs.  (Using gnome everything works).

My first thought was to find out for example the className of ReadItLater using xprop |grep CLASS, and add something like this in my xmonad.hs:

```
  , resource  =? "readitlater"       --> doIgnore
```

However, this doesn't work since if the list is open mouse and keyboard control are bound to the list.

Any ideas how to make tag editing work in read it later under xmonad?

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on the xmonad mailing list or even filing a bug at xmonad bug tracker. Also screenshots of the right and the wrong behaviour would be helpful for people who haven't used this extension to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

A trick which may help to get the props:

```
$ sleep 10s; xprop | grep CLASS
```

Then go to firefox and invoke the extension. In 10 seconds `xprop` will be activated.

Comment: Thanks, however it gives me:  xprop: error: Can't grab the mouse.